# "?!" in regular expression

Tags: python, python-re

```py
import re
a = re.compile('^a(?!abc)')
b = re.compile('^a(?!bac)$')
c = re.compile('^a((?!ba).)*$')

a1 = "abbc"
print(a.search(a1)) # <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
print(b.search(a1)) # None
print(c.search(a1)) # <re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abbc'>
```

I don't understand the expression "?!" in python Regular expression.

Why is only `a` searched in the first case?

I wonder if all the characters of `abbc` can be searched because it is a match that the string `abc` does not come next.

Why is `b` none?

Doesn't it all apply to `abbc` since it starts with `a` and doesn't end with `bac`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: It may be easier to search that document for _negative lookahead assertion_, but it **is** documented and you should absolutely read the docs first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand the expression "?!" in python Regular expression

Well, `?!` is *not* an expression, regular or otherwise.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) says:

> - `(?=...)`
>
>   Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.

> - `(?!...)`
>
>   Matches if `...` doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?!Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s **not** followed by `'Asimov'`.

(including the definition of a positive lookahead assertion for comparison).

So, the expression is really `(?!...)`.

Note that the `(?` sequence is used for several extensions to plain regular expressions, and they're all documented.

> Why is only a searched in the first case?

Because `a` is the only character the pattern asks for. The lookahead group could *prevent* `a` from matching (if it was followed by `abc`), but it wouldn't be part of the match either way.